# Header user to his profile page when he logs in

Tags: php, sql

How can i header user to his profile  page when he logs in.I have got this code

```
$way="user/$userName.php";
$file="main.php";
$m= file_get_contents($file);
if(!file_exists("$way")){
    file_put_contents($way, $m);
}
```

So when new user registers it creates new file for him

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `header("Location: ".$way);` to redirect the user to his/her profile page.

Comment: It stays on the same page now

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that most sites use:

If your `DB` is set up like most sites, you'll have a unique `user_id` for every user (if you don't you're probably not using normalized data and need to do this). When a user logs in, get his/her user_id (usually from a `SESSION` or `cookie`) and make use of PHP's [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/profile.php?id=user_id_here');
```

On the `profile.php` page, you can have a catcher for getting the `GET` variables from the URL:

```
$profile_id = $_GET['id'];
//Parse accordingly
```

Comment: Yes i have user id but i dont use it in url cause it is auto increment so it will be easy to hack

Comment: Easy to hack? What do you mean by easy to hack? A hacker hardly gains much when he figures out a `user_id`

Comment: For exampple someone id is 90910 he or she can type 90911 and he will be logd in other persons profile

Comment: So you only want the owner of a user profile to view their profile? So there are no public profiles? And they will not be logged in (unless you're tracking log_in sessions without `sessions` and tokened `cookies`, which if you are, is very bad practice). They'd have to steal their `token` or hijack your PHP server (like root access or FTP access)

Comment: Okay so i'll try your way

Comment: I don't mean to impose, but I'm just trying to figure out what system you're using to track user logins so I can help better (if you want it). Also, in response to the easiness to hack if a hacker knows someone user_id, if your column is `auto_incremented` any one with basic knowledge in sites could just guess from 1 to infinity and infinitely load your profile page to figure out any user's user_id

Comment: I have tried something similar "$uri=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT userId FROM websiteusers WHERE userName=$usernamer");       
  $_SESSION['profile_id']=$profile_id;
    header("location: main.php?id=$uri"); is this right

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish with your profile page? Do you want anyone to be able to see it or only the owner?

Comment: Like in facebook everybody can see it and follow but there are some things only owner can see like chats etc